# Is this problem about the integral $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}tf(t)dt$ well-posed?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f\in \mathcal{C}[0,1]$ and suppose that:

1. $f(1)=2$.
2. $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=\frac{1}{3}$.
3. $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}f'(x)dx=\frac{25}{3}$.

Find $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx$.

**My approach:** Since that $f\in \mathcal{C}[0,1]$ so, the integrations by parts is well-allowed. Then, we have $$\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=f(1)-\int_{0}^{1}x(f(x)+xf'(x))dx=2-\int_{0}^{1}x(f(x)+xf'(x))dx$$
since that $u=xf(x) \implies du=f(x)+xf'(x)$ and $dv=dx\implies v=x$, then $$\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=\left.x^{2}f(x)\right|_{x=0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}x(f(x)+xf'(x))dx=2-\int_{0}^{1}x(f(x)-xf'(x))dx$$
So, we have $$2\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=2-\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}f'(x)dx$$
Note that  $$\int_{0}^{1}xf'(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}f'(x)dx-\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=\frac{25}{3}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{24}{3}$$
Now, since that $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}f'(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}f'(x)dx-\int_{0}^{1}2xf(x)dx$$
so, $$2\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=2-\frac{25}{3}+2\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx$$
but it's an absurd.

**New approach (corrections):** Since that $f\in \mathcal{C}^{2}[0,1]$, so the integrations by parts is well-allowed. Then $$\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=f(1)-\int_{0}^{1}x(f(x)+xf'(x))dx$$
So, we have that $$2\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=2-\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}f'(x)dx$$
but,  $$\int xf'(x)dx=xf(x)-\int f(x)dx=xf(x)-F(x) \implies \left. \int xf'(x)dx \right|_{x=0}^{1}=\left. xf(x)-F(x)\right|_{x=0}^{1}=f(1)-F(1)+F(0)$$
now,since that $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}f'(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}x(xf'(x))dx=\left.\int xf'(x)dx\right|_{x=0}^{x=1}-\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{x} tf'(t)dt\right)dx=2-F(1)-F(0)-\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{x} tf'(t)dt\right)dx$$

**but I don't know how to continue from here**

Comment: Can you explain precisely how you get $\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=f(1)-\int_{0}^{1}x(f(x)+xf'(x))dx$ using integration by parts?

Comment: ok, I'm going to show that part.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I added that part.

Comment: Also, what is the question?

Comment: second to last line: $\int_0^1 x^2 f' = f(1) - \int_0^1 2xf$ which is not that what you have wrtten. (because $f(0)$ might be non zero)

Comment: @lcv the question is: "what's my mistake?"

Comment: Ok but what are you trying to prove given 1.,2.,3. ?

Comment: ah, sorry. I forgot the question :(

Comment: @lcv I added the question.

Comment: @daw Oh, you're right.

Comment: In the end it seems there is no way around needing to find $\int_0^1 \int_0^x f(y) \, dy \, dx$, and I see no way to determine this quantity using the given information. (Though if the problem is just finding $f(0)$, that can be done using (1),(3), and the FTC.)

Comment: I added a new approach, but I can't continue from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have an $f$ so that

1. $f(1)=2$
2. $\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac13$
3. $\int_0^1f'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{25}3$

and, for some $I$, we have
$$
\int_0^1xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=I
$$

Then, $f(x)+\alpha\sin(2\pi x)$ also satisfies 1., 2., and 3., however
$$
\int_0^1x(f(x)+\alpha\sin(2\pi x))\,\mathrm{d}x=I-\frac\alpha{2\pi}
$$
Thus, we cannot determine $\int_0^1xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ simply based on 1., 2., and 3.

Comment: So, the problem is no well-posed? right?

Comment: The problem is not well-posed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where

$$\int_{0}^{1}xf'(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}f'(x)dx-\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$$ is coming from. If using integration by part, I would say

$$\int_{0}^{1}xf'(x)dx = \left.xf(x)\right|_{x=0}^{1} - \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx = 2-\frac{1}{3} = \frac{5}{3}$$

Comment: Uhm, so I think I'm doing wrong integration by parts and misusing FCT.